# Is a `std::mt19937` static function variable thread-safe?

Tags: c++, random, thread-safety, c++20, mt19937

I have a function `rand_double()` which generates a random floating-point value using a *static function variable* with type `std::mt19937`. Several threads may use this function concurrently.

```cpp
#include <random>

auto random_double(double min, double max) {
    static std::mt19937 generator{std::random_device{}()}; // Forgot to seed it, thanks @user4581301
    return std::uniform_real_distribution<>{min, max}(generator);
}
```

My first question is, **is the above code as-is thread safe**? I know that since C++11 the *initialization* of static function variables is always thread-safe, but how about the concurrent use of generator?

Comment: No. To make it thread safe would materially reduce performance.  I make a generator for each thread.

Comment: Usually cppreference and the Standard call it out when something is thread safe and it's safety is not explicitly stated, it's not safe. I'm seeing no call-outs.

Comment: Side note: You might want to seed the generator.

Comment: No, accessing the generator concurrently on different threads is *not* safe - unless you explicitly make it so.

Comment: @user4581301 Yep. You need a different seed for each generator in each thread.

Comment: @doug "thread safe would materially reduce performance. I make a generator for each thread" - Well, depending on your usage, that may be a bit overkill. `mt19937` can output hundreds of megabytes of pseudo random numbers per second and even if you add the overhead of - say - a `std::mutex`, that's still going to be more than fast enough for 99+% of all use cases out there. But no, it's not thread safe.

Comment: @JesperJuhl. When I've needed a prng it's for really large sample qtys with a short turn around time and a mutex would really slow it down. All depends on the app of course.

Comment: @dough When *I've* needed a prng it's been for making random choices in games or similar and drawing a few random numbers a second has usually been the max, so the overhead of a mutex is completely negligeble.

Comment: But still not something you'd force on everyone by building thread safety in.

Comment: @user4581301 "But still not something you'd force on everyone by building thread safety in" - Depends entirely on what you are doing. If you are building a library that you know will always be used in multithreaded applications and where thread safety is paramount, then building in thread safety seems like the right bet.

Comment: @Jesper  Sorry for being unclear. I'm taking about adding thread safety requirement to the Standard Library. If project X, needs thread-safe RNG, then damn straight. You build a wrapper.

Comment: @doug -- not necessarily. It depends on what the threads do with the generated numbers.

Comment: @PeteBecker My typical use of prngs is Monte-Carlo sims. They often pull tens of millions calls to the prng per sec. A mutex isn't going to hack it. Nikos' answer is pretty close to what I have to do.

Comment: @doug -- I was referring to your comment that you have to seed the generator with a different seed in each thread. Sorry that wasn't clearer...

Comment: @PeteBecker  No problem. Thanks for the clarification. It's an interesting question that  very much depends  on the app.

Comment: Unrelated to the main question. Distributions could be expensive to construct. They should be constructed only once and then _reused_ each time a random number is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To generate a random number, the `std::uniform_real_distribution` calls `operator()` of  the argument generator.

In case of [mersenne twister](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine/operator()) the operator has the side effect:

> "The state of the engine is advanced by one position"

which is not (by any indicator) considered a thread-safe operation.

You can use it as `thread_local` which would have the intended effect i.e. `static` in each specific thread:

```cpp
auto random_double(double min, double max) {
    thread_local std::mt19937 generator(std::random_device{}());
    return std::uniform_real_distribution<>{min, max}(generator);
}
```

Comment: Not that it often matters much but if uniform distribution is important, keep a `thread_local` instance of that too since it has "memory" (state).

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for the suggestions, omitting the random device was a copy paste error but it's more than a nitpick

Comment: Did not know about `thread_local` until today. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

##### `thread_local` is the way to go

The OP asks:

> Is a `std::mt19937` static function variable thread-safe?

In a word, no. As was identified in the comments, calling `operator()` on a `std::mt19937` object is not thread safe.

For applications that make many calls to `std::mt19937`, declaring  the engine to be `thread_local` is best solution. That way, each thread will get it's own instance of the random number engine.

##### Using `param_type` with a random number distribution

By making `std::uniform_real_distribution` thread_local, as well, you can speed things up a tiny bit . That avoids an unnecessary constructor call every time you generate a random number.

To make this work, you must supply a `param_type` object to `uniform_real_distribution`, together with the `std::mt19937` object, when you generate a random number.

In the function below, `param_type{ min, max }` constructs a temporary param object, and initializes it with `min` and `max`.

```cpp
auto random_double(double const min, double const max)
{
    thread_local std::mt19937 mt{ std::random_device{}() };
    thread_local std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist;
    using param_type = std::uniform_real_distribution<double>::param_type;
    return dist(mt, param_type{ min, max });
}
```

This is the most direct solution to the question from the OP.

As an alternative, you can speed things up even more by constructing a `param` object before you call function `random_double`, and reuse it for multiple invocations.

```cpp
using param_type = std::uniform_real_distribution<double>::param_type;

auto random_double(param_type const& p)
{
    thread_local std::mt19937 mt{ std::random_device{}() };
    thread_local std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist;
    return dist(mt, p);  // p is passed by const& straight through to distribution function.
}

void some_function()
{
    // Construct the `param` object once, ...
    param_type p{ -100.0, +100.0 };

    // and use it many times.
    for (int n{ 10 }; n--; )
        std::cout << "   " << random_double(p);
    std::cout.put('\n');
}
```

##### What if `min` and `max` are constant?

If `min` and `max` never change, you make things even more efficient by hard-coding them. This version of function `random_double` avoids the overhead of passing in the arguments `min` and `max`. For the example below, I have set them, respectively, to `1.0` and `10.0`.

```cpp
auto random_double()
{
    thread_local std::mt19937 mt{ std::random_device{}() };
    thread_local std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist{ 1.0, 10.0 };
    return dist(mt);
}
```

##### Use `std::next_after` if you need a closed interval

The C++ Standard requires that the random numbers returned by a `std::uniform_real_distribution` object are uniformly distributed over a half-open interval, say [a,b). Thus, they are greater than or equal to `a`, and less than (but never equal to) `b`.

To create a distribution over the closed interval [a,b], `std::nextafter(b, std::numeric_limits<RealType>::max())` can be used as the second argument of a distribution object's constructor. The same is true for calls to function `param` and the `operator()` call function.

##### Best way to seed `std::mt19937` using `std::random_device`

`std::mt19937` and `std::19937_64` both have 19,968 bits of state, so trying to seed them with a single seed of only 32 or 64 bits is borderline foolish.

To make it easy to seed all 19,968 bits of state, I wrote class `seed_seq_rd`. `seed_seq_rd` stands for *seed-sequence using random-device*. This class mimics the interface of `std::seed_seq`, but uses `std::random_device` to generate seeds. Objects of this type are seed sequences that can be used as arguments to member function `seed` in a random number engine.

```cpp
// Example: Seed mt19937 with random seeds from std::random_device.
tbx::seed_seq_rd s;
std::mt19937 mt;
mt.seed( s );
```

A `seed_seq_rd` object can also be used as an argument to the constructor of a random number engine, and anywhere else that a `std:seed_seq` object can be used.

```cpp
// Example: Seed mt19937_64 at the time of its construction.
tbx::seed_seq_rd s;
std::mt19937_64 mt64{ s };
```

The souce code for `seed_seq_rd` is available in a [single-file header on GitHub](https://github.com/tbxfreeware/seed_randomly). It works with any random number engine that can be seeded with a seed-sequence, including all of the engines in the Standard Library.

Class `seed_seq_rd` is defined in header `tbx.cpp14.seed_randomly.h`. (It uses only the features of C++14, nothing later. Hence the name.) Using it to seed `std::mt19937`, would change your function to something like the following.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include "tbx.cpp14.seed_randomly.h"

auto random_double(double const min, double const max)
{
    thread_local tbx::seed_seq_rd s;  // uses only 4 bytes of storage!
    thread_local std::mt19937 mt{ s };
    thread_local std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist;
    using param_type = std::uniform_real_distribution<double>::param_type;
    return dist(mt, param_type{ min, max });
}

int main()
{
    for (int n{ 10 }; n--; )
        std::cout << "   " << random_double(-5.0, +5.0);
    std::cout.put('\n');
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

Output:

```
   -1.95065   4.29782   2.23657   -1.3178   4.73166   -2.22954   -3.14094   4.15405   0.847722   2.52301
```